# String Format fixed bound chars, variable chars inside

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I want to format a number as string in a format like this:

```
String.Format(phone, "(00) ##000\-0000");
```

So:

```
112349999   -> (11) 234-9999
1123459999  -> (11) 2345-9999
11234569999 -> (11) 23456-9999
```

(Will be read just these phones formatting that are allowed in my country)

1. With 2 first digits fixed in "(XX)".
2. Last 4 digits fixed "-XXXX"
3. Inner digits (others digits), starts from "-" (every char beig inserted at 6th position from the right, pushing another to (XX) ).

I'm unable to achieve this behavior with a simple format with String.Format().

Is there a way?

Comment: I don't think a simple format string can be used here because the second part has a variable number of digits. I'd recommend simple string manipulation.

Comment: so you want 123456789 formatted as (12) 543-6789 or as (12) 345-6789? As you already have the correct format for the latter format, I am assuming the first one and that is not possible with simple string formatting.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry it was dubious.. I want as (12) 345-6789. Updated my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string phone = "112223333";
var m = Regex.Match(phone, @"(\d{2})(\d+)(\d{4})");
var formatted = String.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[3].Value);
```

Comment: Nice solution.  `Regex` seems a bit heavy for the simple case, but this would easily extend to a wide variety of phone formats.

Answer (score 0):

Since the middle part has a variable number of digits, you won't be able to use `String.Format` here.  Try this instead:

```
String.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}",
    phone.Substring(0, 2),
    phone.Substring(2, phone.Length - 6),
    phone.Substring(phone.Length - 4))
);
```